# guest crash on long backup via rsync

Tags: linux, vmware-server

I recently upgraded host to Ubuntu 9.10 with vmware server 2.0.2, i had two guest machine. One is a sme server i had several crash during a session of backup with rsync to another pc. Normal activities run regularly. The other guest is up without problem since 25 days.

I found in the log a lot o f row like these

```
 Dec 20 05:29:27.445: vcpu-1| VLANCE: Ethernet0 skipped 2560 time(s)
 Dec 20 05:29:27.445: vcpu-1| VLANCE: 66 12 5 8 2 3 3 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 2 0
 Dec 20 05:29:27.445: vcpu-1| VLANCE: 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 2452
 Dec 20 05:29:27.651: vmx| ide0:0: Command WRITE(10) took 1.947 seconds (ok)
 Dec 20 05:29:37.945: vmx| ide0:0: Command WRITE(10) took 1.033 seconds (ok)
```

when the vitual machine crash the log report, I paste here only some part to limit the lenght of the message

```
 Dec 27 01:48:05.686: Worker#2| Caught signal 6 -- tid 700
 Dec 27 01:48:05.686: Worker#2| SIGNAL: eip 0x460422 esp 0xb124c024 ebp 0xb124c03
 Dec 27 01:48:05.712: Worker#2| SymBacktrace12 00000000 eip 0x39d7ee in function clone in object /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 loaded at 0x2d1000
 Dec 27 01:48:05.719: Worker#2| Unexpected signal: 6.
 Dec 27 01:48:05.720: Worker#2| Core dump limit is 0 KB.
 Dec 27 01:48:05.762: Worker#2| Child process 10455 failed to dump core (status 0
```

x6).

```
 Dec 27 01:48:05.762: Worker#2|SymBacktrace13 00000000 eip 0x39d7ee in function clone in object /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 loaded at 0x2d1000
 Dec 27 01:48:05.779: Worker#2|Msg_Post: Error
 Dec 27 01:48:05.780: Worker#2|http://msg.log.error.unrecoverable VMware Server unrecoverable error: (Worker#2)
 Dec 27 01:48:05.780: Worker#2|Unexpected signal: 6.
```

I have no idea how to solve the problem with this installation, I think to dowgrade the host to a version more compatible with vmware server 2. I read a lot of post about difficult of installation I think the problem of compilation during install could be related to my problem.

Excuse me if the post isn't very clear, it's my first post here.

Any help or suggest will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue similar to this when I upgraded an Ubuntu host running VMWare server.  I upgraded from 8.04 to 9.10 running VMWare server 2.0.2 and was having issues with a few Linux guests crashing constantly and windows guests not even running.  I did a little research around and found lots of people having issues on Ubuntu 9.10 after an upgrade but not a clean install.  My solution was to backup my virtual machines to a different location just to be careful and re-install VMWare server 2.0.2.  That worked for me, I believe the issue was that the 2.0.2 was installed under 8.04 which has different versions of core components and, at least on my server, was running an older kernel.

I would suggest trying to re-compile 2.0.2 on 9.10 before downgrading Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

That might be a Virtual to hardware translation problem, as said Shadow00Caster, updating a 8.04 to 9.10 without recompiling should cause some trouble to the Operating system who not manage the request as the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem stems from VMware Server 2 being incompatible/buggy with `glibc` versions above 2.5-34.  I've experienced this from upgrading CentOS 5.3 to 5.4 and this bug has been [documented](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=3884) in the CentOS/RHEL distribution. From reading your error log, the errors associated with `libc.so.6` are very similar and I can only assume that it's affecting Ubuntu the same way. Try downgrading to an older version of glibc (it worked for me in CentOS+assuming it won't break other packages you have installed) or downgrading Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same problem with CentOS 5.4 which was a glibc issue. See this post for details and a workaround CentOS 5.4 glibc causes crash of VMWare vmware-hostd process in VMWare 2.0.0 and 2.0.1, http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=3884 and specifically comment (0010880)